# Image of a subgroup under a homomorphism is not a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've seen a plethora of examples that when a normal subgroup $H_{1} \unlhd G_{1}$ is mapped via a homomorphism $\phi\colon G_{1} \to G_{2}$, the resulting image under the homomorphism $\phi(H_{1})$ is also normal.

My intuition tells me that in general, a regular 'ole subgroup, call it $N_{1} \le G_{1}$, could also be normal under $\phi$, but I'm curious as to under which general conditions this occurs.

Thanks!

Comment: Given complete freedom in terms of $\varphi$ it is easy to make $\varphi(N)$ normal: simply have $\varphi$ map all of $N$, or better yet all of $G_1$, to the identity element of $G_2$. Then regardless of how $N$ sits inside $G_1$ or of the structure of $G_2$, $\varphi(N)$ will be a normal subgroup of $G_2$. (Conversely, re: your first sentence note that in general normal subgroups need *not* be mapped to normal subgroups - that's only guaranteed if $\varphi$ is surjective.)

Comment: Yep, you're super right on both counts – thanks for the comment!! I suppose that when I was writing the question I was thinking more about examples where something interesting occurs with the homomorphism or the structure of the groups. The trivial homomorphism you outlined was a great way to tease out what I was actually trying to say!

Answer (score 0):

If $N_{1} \unlhd G_{1}$ and $\phi\colon G_{1} \to G_{2}$ is a surjective group homomorphism then $\phi(N_1)\unlhd G_2$.

Btw, if $G_2$ is abelian then any subgroup of $G_2$ is normal.

Comment: All of what you said is correct, but I suppose I was more looking for some interesting examples of cases where the group structure or something clever in the construction of the homomorphism enables a subgroup to get mapped to a normal subgroup.